# My Kotlin project Cannot resolve dependencies on Travis-CI

Tags: gradle, jvm, travis-ci, kotlin

I In an attempt to integrate my Kotlin project with Travis-CI, can not generate a successfully build, I get message that my gradle not found the repository ...

The repository is in my file build.gradle

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-4584"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://repository.jetbrains.com/all"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.spek:spek:0.1.188'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.0-beta-4584"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

My travis is very simple

```
language: java
```

The message received is

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'dojo-s01e01-cheque-por-extenso'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-beta-4584 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         :dojo-s01e01-cheque-por-extenso:unspecified
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED
```

the Link to build is -> https://travis-ci.org/castrolol/dojo-s01e01-cheque-por-extenso.kotlin/builds/127235950

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}
```

to your `buildscript { ... }` scope as well.

Also, consider using a newer Kotlin version, the up-to-date one can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html).